# filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model is null in ActionFilter.OnActionExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, action-filter, t4mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project with a POST action that model binds to a viewmodel

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Reply(ReplyViewModel viewModel)
{
    // ...
}
```

I have an `ActionFilter` and I want to look at that viewmodel in `OnActionExecuted` but `ViewData.Model` is null. Am I misunderstanding what `ViewData.Model` is?

```
public class CopyViewModelToTempDataAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a Solution to this problem 
1. I assume that you assigned Model in Action

now come to Filter

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
        // Get your model here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I assume that you assigned Model in Action" - no I assumed the framework automatically populated it. Is there a generic way to get to the parameters of the Action that was called prior to the OnActionExecuted through the filterContext?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller action must pass a view model when returning the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Reply(ReplyViewModel viewModel)
{
    // ...
    return View(someViewModel);
}
```

Now you will be able to fetch the returned view model in the action filter.